# Clustering On Labelled Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I've seen posts discussing clustering on labelled datasets. Below is an approach I'm considering. IN short, I would be clustering "base data" vs. "XAI-calculated" data to see how the XAI-calculated data discriminates better. Do the steps below make sense?

0. Note: raw dataset is labelled, i.e., includes a binary target outcome variable
1. Apply predictive machine learning model, e.g., random forest, XGBoost, or some other ensemble algorithm
2. Apply PCA (principal component analysis) - on **model or raw data?** - to determine top features for clustering later
3. Calculate an XAI (explainable AI) metric on predictive model
4. Cluster (k-means) the XAI metrics - is this **OK even though the raw dataset is labelled**?
5. Cluster the raw data values from the PCA step #2 above
6. Compare the clustering results between #4, #5 through clustering metrics (completeness, homogeneity, etc)
7. Apply a statistical inference test like t-test to see whether differences are significant between XAI-generated results vs. base data results - **this part is a bit foggy to me**, not sure if it can be done here?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My questions and problem related to the above are the following: - When I apply PCA, my understanding is, it is on the raw data, not predicted output? - I assume it is OK to apply (unsupervised) k-means cluster to a labelled dataset if I am clustering based on the top two features identified by Shapley values (XAI metric) - To test my hypothesis as to whether Shapley values are more effective at discriminating data than base data alone, I was going to perform a t-test on the clustering metrics based on Shapley values vs. clustering metrics using base data. The base data would be without any mo